# Perl reports wrong line number if dying in multi line substitution. Is this expected or a bug?

Tags: windows, perl

When I run the following code, the script dies with `expected three at c:\temp\die.pl line 13.`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $text = 'one two Three';

$text =~ s{

  (\w+)  # Find a word
  \s+
  (\w+)  # Find another word
  \s+
  (\w+)  # Find third word

}{

   # Insert a few lines on purpose
   # to make the point.

   die 'expected one'   unless $1 eq 'one';
   die 'expected two'   unless $2 eq 'two';
   die 'expected three' unless $3 eq 'three';

}ex;
```

I am somewhat surprised because the actual line that causes the death is line 21.

It seems that the interpreter does not count the pattern part of the substitution when it calculates(?) the line of death. Line 6 would be `$text =~ s{` then the code until `}{` is "skipped", making line 7 the following empty line, line 8 `# Insert a few lines on purpose` and so on until it reaches `die 'expected three' unless $3 eq 'three';` having counted 13 lines.

Is this behaviour expected?

Is there a way to have perl print the real line of death?

`perl -v` starts with `This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 1 (v5.18.1) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int`

## Using carp instead of die

It was suggested I use `carp` instead of `die`.

It now dies (or carps) with the only slightly different `expected three at c:\temp\die.pl line 14` which I attribute to the additional third line `use Carp;`.

Comment: in linux it indeed dies at line 21

Comment: You can print full error via `Carp` -- it would be interesting to see what is reported, given this behavior.  My guess here would be that the broken-up regex that counts differently.. I can come up with "13" by counting each regex part as one line and discarding empty lines inside the regex, what I can imagine being done.

Comment: For me, with v5.16 on CentOS 7, it also dies on the last blank line before `}{`.

Comment: @sotona do you have a Perl version > 5.18?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger exactly. I tested also on 5.16 and it indeed complains on 13th line.

Comment: So that seems to indicate that this is a bug fixed in a release after 5.18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick bit of investigation showed this:

`v5.10.1` dies on line 13.
`v5.18.4` dies on line 13.
`v5.20.2` dies on line 21.
`v5.22.0` dies on line 21.

Then after checking the [perldelta for 5.20](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.20.0/perldelta.html#Everything-Else), I found:

> Line numbers inside multiline quote-like operators are now reported correctly. [perl #3643]

So, it seems the only way to get the right line number would be to upgrade to a later version of perl.